# Store SQLite query result in a String array

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

How can I save a query result in a String array?
The query is simple, it's got only one column i.e.:

```
SELECT NAME FROM MYTABLE
```

What I want is to store the ids in a String array so I can show them as clickable items in a `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM table";
        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
                    ids.add(id);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already executed your query against a [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase) object, and received a [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) in return, you can iterate through the cursor and save the value of each row to a `String[]` array like so:

```
String[] names;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    names = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");
    do {
        names[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getString(colIndex);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Keep in mind that `names` will be `null` if no rows are returned, so make sure you do a null check.

Answer (score 0):

create following method in SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
public List<String> getAllNames() {
    List<String> retData = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM MYTABLE";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            retData.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return retData;
}
```

then assign this returned list to adapter

Answer (score 0):

The issue with listing **id**'s is that they tend to be meaningless to an end user. Really you want to display user meaningful data, e.g. a name, but to then be able to access the respective **id** to then efficiently act on a selection from the list presented to a user.

Using an ArrayList is frequently the cause of much frustration, as the list shows what is required but it's then found to be of little use when attempting to use the list beyond displaying data e.g. selecting an item to then do something such as delete or update (if the value is unique within the database it can be used).

As such an `ArrayList<your_object>` rather then an `ArrayList<String>` is generally more viable as the source of the List; a Cursor Adapter can also be used as data from the underlying row is easily obtained.

However, there is an issue, unless a Custom Array Adapter is utilised, when using an ArrayList in that the `ArrayAdapter` class uses the `toString` method of the object to retrieve the data that is displayed. The simple fix is to provide a suitable `toString` method in the object, if you don't you will get something long the lines of `“SomeType@2f92e0f4”`.

#### Example showing all 3

In the following working example :-

- the database (**mydb**) has 1 table named **mytable** which has two columns **_id** *(Note must be **_id** for a CursorAdapter)*
- There are 3 methods to get the 3 types of list (named accordingly) :-

  1. **getAllAsStringArrayList** *(gets ArrayList)*
  2. **getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList** *(gets ArrayList)*. Note uses the **MyTableObject** class (see note in class re overriding the default **toString** method)
  3. **getAllAsCursor**

     - The App, when run, will have 3 lists, the left based upon the first ArrayList, the middle based upon the ArrayList and the last based upon the Cursor.
     - Clicking an item in any of the lists displays the respective name along with attempts to get the **id**.
     - The **ArrayList**, Left List, fails in this aspect as it can only get the position (i.e. the 4th parameter passed to the listener is the same value as the position).
     - The ArrayList, middle List, when getting the **id** from the object (which is retrieved via the getItem(position) method of the Adapter) successfully retrieves the correct **id**, the 4th parameter is the same as the position, and should not be used.
     - The Cursor, Right List, retrieves the correct **id** both via the Cursor and the 4th parameter.

**The Code**

**MyTableObject.java** :-

```
public class MyTableObject {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public MyTableObject(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    /*
        NOTE toString method returns just the name
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java** :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COl_MYTABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID; //<<<< use standard android id column name
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_NAME = "_name";

    private static final String mytable_crtsql =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_MYTABLE +
                    "(" +
                    COl_MYTABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    COL_MYTABLE_NAME + " TEXT " +
                    ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(mytable_crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRow(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TB_MYTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllAsStringArrayList() {
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_MYTABLE_NAME)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyTableObject> getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList() {
        ArrayList<MyTableObject> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(new MyTableObject(
                    csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_MYTABLE_ID)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_MYTABLE_NAME))
                    )
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
        return mDB.query(
                TB_MYTABLE,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    ListView mListView01,mListVeiw02,mListView03;

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterStringArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<MyTableObject> mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapterCursor;

    ArrayList<String> mMyTableListAsStrings;
    ArrayList<MyTableObject> mMyTableAsObjects;
    Cursor mMyTableListAsCursor;

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mListView01 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview01);
        mListVeiw02 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview02);
        mListView03 = this.findViewById(R.id.listview03);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Bert");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Harry");
        mDBHlpr.addRow("Fred");

        //String Array List
        mMyTableListAsStrings = mDBHlpr.getAllAsStringArrayList();
        mAdapterStringArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsStrings
        );
        mListView01.setAdapter(mAdapterStringArrayList);


        //Object Array List
        mMyTableAsObjects = mDBHlpr.getAllAsMyTableObjectArrayList();
        mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableAsObjects
        );
        mListVeiw02.setAdapter(mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList);

        // Cursor
        mMyTableListAsCursor = mDBHlpr.getAllAsCursor();
        mAdapterCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mMyTableListAsCursor,
                new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mListView03.setAdapter(mAdapterCursor);


        mListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = mAdapterStringArrayList.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID is " + String.valueOf(id) +
                                " (note may not match)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mListVeiw02.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                MyTableObject mytable = mAdapterMyTableObjectArrayList.getItem(position);
                String name = mytable.getName();
                long id_in_object = mytable.getId();
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_object) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });

        mListView03.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor csr = mAdapterCursor.getCursor(); // already positioned
                String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_MYTABLE_NAME));
                long id_in_cursor = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COl_MYTABLE_ID));
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Name is " + name  +
                                ". ID from object is " + String.valueOf(id_in_cursor) +
                                ". ID from adapter is " + String.valueOf(id),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```