# Hopefully an easy one, how do I store the names of tables in an array using sqlite and java in android studio?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I need to put the names of the tables in my database "Workouts.db" into an array so i can use a spinner to allow the user to select which table is being displayed in recyclerview

I dont want the table named "ViewWorkout" to be stored in the variable but i do want the rest of the tables in my database to be added

my plan is to use this array to populate a spinner, get the item selected when i click a button and  insert the data from the selected table into the "ViewWorkout" table which will be displayed in recycler view

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' and name <> 'ViewWorkout' ORDER BY 1` should give you that list.

Comment: Thanks so much, how would i go about putting the results of that query into an array?

Comment: See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061461/store-sqlite-query-result-in-a-string-array).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.